# What to call this implementation pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming-conventions

In the code below I have realized that naming them "Sender" is probably wrong and the `Send` method is better to be moved to another class.

What's really going on is a single type of object is getting created from multiple sources, each source containing some common inputs (handled in the base sender) and more specific inputs (handled in the derived sender).

What should I rename these classes to, assuming I move the `Send` method out to a helper class?

```
abstract class LoanEventSenderBase<T> where T : LoanEvent, new()
{
    protected readonly T LoanEvent;
    protected string Topic;

    protected LoanEventSenderBase(ILoans loans)
    {
        LoanEvent = new T
        {
            LoanNumber = loans.CurrentLoan.LoanNumber,
            LasedUsedByUser = loans.UserFullName
        };
    }
    public void Send() {
    }
}
class LoanMajorEventSender : LoanEventSenderBase<LoanMajorEvent>
{
    public LoanMajorEventSender(ILoans loans, int majorEventNum)
        : base(loans)
    {
        LoanEvent.MajorEventNum = majorEventNum;
        Topic = string.Format("{0}.{1}", LoanEvent.GetType().Name, LoanEvent.MajorEventNum);
    }
}
class LoanFieldEventSender : LoanEventSenderBase<LoanFieldEvent>
{
    public LoanFieldEventSender(ILoans loans, LoanFieldEventArgs loanFieldEventArgs)
        : base(loans)
    {
        LoanEvent.OldValue = loanFieldEventArgs.OldValue.ToString();
        LoanEvent.NewValue = loanFieldEventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
        LoanEvent.FieldName = loanFieldEventArgs.LoanField.DataDefinition.XmlName;
        LoanEvent.FieldNumber = loanFieldEventArgs.LoanField.DataDefinition.FieldNumber;
        Topic = string.Format("{0}.{1}", LoanEvent.GetType().Name, LoanEvent.FieldNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that asking a question on "renaming a class" should be asked on Code Review.

Comment: Some kind of `Builder`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review site

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I like that - each derived class does one thing: builds a LoanEvent - if you put that in as an answer I'll gladly mark it (unless this question gets closed)

Comment: As a series of derived classes, I wouldn't call it "Builder".  "Builder" is generally one class that takes parameters for the construction independently and is then asked to create an instance *after* the parameters are set.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: I don't think this is a known pattern or anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone with the builder suggestion.

```
class Message<T> where T : LoanEvent
{
    public T LoanEvent { get; protected set; }
    public string Topic { get; protected set; }
}
class MessageSender
{
    public void Send<T>(Message<T> message) where T : LoanEvent
    {
    }
}
abstract class MessageBuilder<T> : Message<T> where T : LoanEvent, new()
{
    protected MessageBuilder(ILoans loans)
    {
        LoanEvent = new T
        {
            LoanNumber = loans.CurrentLoan.LoanNumber,
            LasedUsedByUser = loans.UserFullName
        };
    }
}
class LoanMajorEventMessageBuilder : MessageBuilder<LoanMajorEvent>
{
    public LoanMajorEventMessageBuilder(ILoans loans, int majorEventNum)
        : base(loans)
    {
        LoanEvent.MajorEventNum = majorEventNum;
        Topic = string.Format("{0}.{1}", LoanEvent.GetType().Name, LoanEvent.MajorEventNum);
    }
}
class LoanFieldEventMessageBuilder : MessageBuilder<LoanFieldEvent>
{
    public LoanFieldEventMessageBuilder(ILoans loans, LoanFieldEventArgs loanFieldEventArgs)
        : base(loans)
    {
        LoanEvent.OldValue = loanFieldEventArgs.OldValue.ToString();
        LoanEvent.NewValue = loanFieldEventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
        LoanEvent.FieldName = loanFieldEventArgs.LoanField.DataDefinition.XmlName;
        LoanEvent.FieldNumber = loanFieldEventArgs.LoanField.DataDefinition.FieldNumber;
        Topic = string.Format("{0}.{1}", LoanEvent.GetType().Name, LoanEvent.FieldNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this implementation looks more like a part of [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern). It encapsulates a request as an object, thereby allowing to parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests etc.

> naming them "Sender" is probably wrong and the Sendmethod is better to be moved to another class.

You can use *CommandInvoker* class, as suggested by the already mentioned pattern.

Comment: I think he's talking about the construction being across multiple base classes, not the "send" part in the hierarchy.